# 260 Character Limit, Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

I understand there is a 260 character limit for win32, but I am curious as to why my code is *half working*. See below.

```
$Age_of_Files = -30
$Path = '\\share\d$\share'

$Age_of_Files = -30

$Current_Date = Get-Date

$Del_date = $Current_Date.AddDays($Age_of_Files)

$post = "<BR><i>Report generated on $((Get-Date).ToString())</i>"

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Del_date} |
    Select Name, FullName, LastWriteTime 

$Data | ConvertTo-HTML -PreContent $pre -PostContent $post | Out-File $Report

Invoke-Item $Report

Read-Host 'Have you checked the Output File...Ok to Continue with Delete?' | Out-Null
```

This will check my network share with no problem and give me no errors, although there are many directories longer then 260 characters but I also want to export this as a HTML file, so If I change this line of code.

```
 $Data = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse |
         Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Del_date } |
         Select Name, FullName, LastWriteTime
```

It then does not recurse through the directories, and gives me the character limit error.

Is there a way around this? As apart from exporting it to HTML and adding in the actual delete command I think I am nearly there.

Comment: I have a function that I wrote to get around that 260 character limitation: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-ChildItemV2-to-list-29291aae

Comment: Hi Boeprox, I certainly appreciate you sharing your code, I thought this was going to be the answer! But unfortunately it does not do anything when I add the variable $Date = Get-ChildItem2

Comment: Can you expand on that? What do you mean by adding a variable? What happens when you don't add the variable and just run 'as is'? Did you dot source the file to load the function before running the command?

Comment: Hi Boeprox, Yes it works fine without adding the `$Data `  Value, Just as my code did. But to be able to export that data into a HTML file I need to add the data into an array like this `$Data = Get-ChildItem2 $Path -Recurse |
         Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Del_date } |
         Select Name, FullName, LastWriteTime ` This then stops your code from executing, it just does nothing. With the previous code, I start getting the 260 character limit error. I did load the function before running the command.

Comment: I tried running the code you provided in your comment and cannot reproduce the issue that you are describing where the code stops executing. Simply adding $Data to save the output shouldn't prevent the command from executing. Just run it like this and see what happens: `$Data = Get-ChildItem2`

Comment: Hi Boeprox, Thanks again for your reply, I figured out what the issue was, it was nothing to do with your code, It is simply due to the size/amount of data on the network drive, it looks like nothing is happening. I setup a new test drive, copied over just a few GB of data, works like a charm, your code works perfectly! Just what I needed. I will just have to run the script overnight!

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on long paths in Windows 10.  There's a gpo. 
 https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

Answer (score 0):

This is a [limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) of the Win32 API ([see also](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2008/07/07/long-paths-in-net-part-3-of-3-redux-kim-hamilton/)). There's a [PowerShell Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSAlphaFS/1.0.0.0) that supposedly works around the issue (haven't used it myself, though).

A common workaround is to shorten the path by [`subst`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true)ing the longest accessible path to a drive letter

```
& subst X: C:\longest\parent\folder
```

working on drive `X:`, then deleting the temporary drive afterwards:

```
& subst X: /d
```

For network paths use `net use` to the same end:

```
& net use X: \\server\share\longest\parent\folder
...
& net use X: /d
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, Thank you for your answer, I did try this with Net Use, but unfortunately there are many, many sub folders and it didnt work. I am starting to think I need to take a different approach.

Comment: "didn't work" doesn't contain sufficient debugging information.

Comment: The directory length was still too high, even by shortening it.

Comment: Shorten it again. And hit whoever created paths that long with a cluestick.

Comment: Just to avoid confustion, by "longest parent folder" I meant the longest path that doesn't hit the 260 character limit, of course.